# I would be traveling from New York to India through Dubai stop at Athens.Do I need an airport transit visa?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, airports, ath

I am a citizen of India. I will be traveling from New York to India through Dubai and with a stop at Athens (2 hrs). I will stay in the airport (or in the airplane) during the  2 hour stop at the airport in Athens. I will not be going out of the airport. I have a valid US visa. Do I need an airport transit visa?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not leaving the airport, you do not need a visa for either UAE or Greece.